# AspectJ with Spring framework

Tags: spring, aspectj

I have a question. Is it possible to inject spring bean into pure AspectJ project ( Let say we don't use Spring AOP, because of its limitations. We need to advice some static methods. )
And use those spring beans in AspectJ advices. Could we use CTW or LTW?

Comment: Better to add some code samples of what fo you expect.

Comment: Hello. I just need to inject some spring beans to @Aspect annotated class (it should be AcpectJ aspect) and need to have CTW. But, I am wondering, can Spring framework inject dependency during runtime?

Comment: Ivan, why don't you follow Alexey's advice and add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question? This is what people do on StackOverflow in order to get good answers. Show us what you tried and report what problems you had with your approach.